# for loop in bazel template

Tags: templates, bazel

Is it possible to perform a for loop in a template in bazel using the actions.expand_template() call?

I'd like to be able to pass in a list of strings and iterate over them to generate code.  From all I can tell in the examples, you can only provide a flat dict object and perform single substitution.

My template ideally would have something like:

```
{% for k in keys %}
    {{ k }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not possible. You can pass only strings to `expand_template` (so you need to flatten your dictionary in the bzl file).

Answer (score 0):

Seems not possible. But you can write a python script, and use jinja2 to do the complex template rendering. Use a shell script to run this python script and finally get the output file.